# Trying to create a code/function that allows a user to purchase ingredients and then store that in their inventory, confused how?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner Python coder and I'm attempting to create a function that allows a user to purchase/buy 3 different ingredients ('apples','beets', and 'carrots') which are each $1. The function I've defined will take 2 arguments (the ingredient name and how many they want to purchase). The maximum amount of money that the user has is $20.

```html
iinventory={}
iinventory['apple']=0
iinventory['beets']=0
iinventory['carrots']=0

def buyingredient(ingredient_name,number: int):
    total=20
    while total > 0:
        if number > total:
            break
        if number < total:
            iinventory[ingredient_name] += number
            total = total + number
            iinventory.append(number))
```

I'm having trouble on how to actually begin the code since first I have to make sure that the amount they are purchasing is not over their total amount of money ($20). Also, I'm not sure how to put the purchased amount of money into the inventory that is a dictionary. I thought I could use append but I think that's only for lists not dictionaries.

Then however many they buy of apples, beets, or carrots will be reflected on their total and will substract.
For example, if they bought 3 apples:

buyingredient('apple',3)

Then the inventory will say they have 3 apples and a total of $17 left.

iinventory={'apple':3,'beets':0,'carrots':0}
total=17

Not sure where to go from here for the code now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keeping track of the amount you've spent as new ingredients are purchased, then you can avoid that loop:

```
inventory = {
    "apple": 0,
    "beets": 0,
    "carrots": 0}

total_budget = 20
total_spent = 0

def buy_ingredient(name, number):
    if number + total_spent > total_budget:
        raise ValueError("overspent!")
    inventory[name] += number
    total_spent += number
```

Let's try it out (bear with me, I'm going to take a bit of a tangent):

```
>>> buy_ingredient('apple', 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in buy_ingredient
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total_spent' referenced before assignment
```

Gah!

This fails because `total_spent` is defined outside the function. For that reason, it's generally considered bad practice to have functions update variables that "live" outside them - it's preferred to return something instead. (Yes, updating `iinventory` will work, but it's still considered bad style.)

In this case, you're creating something but then modifying it an unknown number of times - a perfect opportunity to take classes for a spin. Let's create a `GroceryBasket` that keeps track of your budget and the items you add:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class GroceryBasket(object):
    def __init__(self, budget):
        self.items = defaultdict(int)
        self.budget = budget
        self.spent_so_far = 0

    def add_ingredient(self, name, number):  # note this is almost exactly the `buy_ingredient` function from above
        if number + self.spent_so_far > self.budget:
            raise ValueError("overspent!")
        self.items[name] += number
        self.spent_so_far += number
```

Create an instance, specifying your budget:

```
>>> basket = GroceryBasket(budget=20)
>>> basket.budget
20
>>> basket.spent_so_far
0
```

Add 5 apples:

```
>>> basket.add_ingredient("apple", 5)
>>>
>>> basket.items
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'apple': 5})
>>>
>>> basket.spent_so_far
5
```

And now 100 beets:

```
>>> basket.add_ingredient('beets', 100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in add_ingredient
ValueError: overspent!
```

Anyway, that's probably more answer than you were looking for, but I wanted to tighten up your function while making the point that it should either return a value or update the state of an object passed in (in this case, `self`) without leaving you hanging. Hope this helps.

(Btw, if you're wondering what `defaultdict` is, take a look at the docs, they're quite good. There's an example that shows the use of `defaultdict(int)` with the `+=` operator not too far down: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: thank you! so for the iinventory i made it as a dictionary and by modifying the amount of apples, beets, and carrots it would modify that in the dictionary. is that hard to do or bad?

Comment: Welcome! That's fine, the `defaultdict` is just a special dictionary that saves you from checking whether an item exists before you try incrementing it - `self.items[name] += number` will fail the first time you encounter each ingredient.

Comment: is there a way to add the bought ingredients into the dictionary iinventory={} ?

Comment: That `while` loop will run forever right now because total can never be less than or equal to `0`, so you really need a bigger-picture refactor to get this working. `iinventory[ingredient_name] += number` is the correct syntax for adding items to `iinventory`, `iinventory.append(number))` needs to be removed. Once you've experimented a little bit, I'd recommend posting your code on codereview.stackexchange.com